# Print page content

Tags: google-chrome-app

I just started playing with google chrome apps. I've searched the internet and haven't found the way to print the content of the windows. Tried using `windows.print()`, but nothing happened.

As far as I have read, the `print()` wont work since it is called in the background.html that does not have any content. How can I make the call at the correct place and send the content of the app to the printer?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing in apps is not yet supported, I believe. See 
Issue [131279](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=131279):  async version of window.print()

Comment: Hello @Vincent, so there is no workaround to make it possible? The app will run only on known computers.

Comment: I suggest you give it a try. Chrome Apps are not exactly the same thing as Chrome Extensions. If you're injecting JS directly into a bwe page it may still work.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that this can't be done through the Background page, since it is not rendered. What you'll need to do is inject a "content script" into the page you would like to print. The content script would contain the print command, and probably whatever would trigger the print command.

In a nutshell, "content scripts" are scripts that are injected into the pages a user browses. You can inject pretty much any JavaScript you like, and even inject entire JavaScript libraries like JQuery. More details can be found here:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html

If you decide to use a popup window to trigger the print you can pass a message to the window you would like to print. Message passing is how the different components of an extension (background page, content script, popup) communicate. More info can be found here:

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html

Comment: thanks for the answer. It was really useful! However I just realized I made a huge mistake. Actually it is an App, not an extension. Do you know how I can print from an App? Thank you @Jude!